# Transform a locale-aware unicode string in a valid Decimal number in Python/Django

Tags: python, django, unicode, localization

In my **Django 1.7.11** app, I get data formatted with a spanish locale via HTTP. So, in my view, I get a unicode string representing a decimal number in spanish locale:

```
spanish_number = request.GET.get('some_post_value', 0)
# spanish_number may be u'12,542' now, for example. And may come via POST. This is not important. Just the value itself is important: it contains commas as decimal separator.
```

And I want to store that in a Django Model's field of type DecimalField:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    my_number = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=3, null=True, blank=True)
```

In my settings.py, I have

```
USE_L10N=True
USE_I18N=True
```

If I try something like

```
m = MyModel()
m.my_number = spanish_number # This is, u'12,542'
m.save()
```

It fails with a ValidationError because

```
u'12,542' must be a decimal number
```

**What would be the right way to deal with this?** I mean, **with the fact that my application is going to receive numbers (and dates...) formatted this way (spanish locale)**

P.S.: I know Django has a [DecimalField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/forms/fields/#decimalfield) for forms, with a localize=True option, but I'm directly dealing with Models, not with Forms.

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track looking at form `DecimalField`. If you check its source, you'll see that when set to localize it runs the string through `formats.sanitize_separators`. You can call this directly to convert to the format `Decimal()` expects:

```
import django.utils.formats
m.my_number = formats.sanitize_separators(spanish_number)
```

Comment: Tried that. Didn't work. But I was debugging the code of sanitize_separator and reading about the settings. Looks like settings like USE_L10N, USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR, etc, are used to define the way in which Django will display numbers. Doesn't say anything about how to do the opposite trip (store localized data). Or I can't find it.

Comment: Hmm. It looks like that function requires `USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR` to be `True` to handle thousands. You could set that to `True` if you want the localized thousand separator to be used in other contexts, reimplement the sanitize function yourself in a way that doesn't depend on it, or do the ugly hack of modifying `settings.USE_THOUSAND_SEPARATOR` before and after sanitizing.